# How can I change the color of selected text?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I need to change the background color of the selected text using codemirror.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 15):

Don't forget the essential `!important`. You need:

```css
.CodeMirror-selected {background-color: #CCCCCC !important;}
```

If you need to also change the selection foreground color, CodeMirror has [the `mark-selection.js` addon](https://codemirror.net/addon/selection/mark-selection.js) to achieve that.

Answer (score 9):

Change the background color for  .CodeMirror-selected {} , the class is located in codemirror.css

```
.CodeMirror-selected {background:#CCCCCC;}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this by overriding the highlight color specific to the CodeMirror theme:

```
/** OVERRIDE SELECTED TEXT HIGHLIGHT COLOR FOR THEMES: **/

    /* isotope theme */
    .cm-s-isotope div.CodeMirror-selected {
        background: #0004FF !important;
    }
    /* colorforth theme */
    .cm-s-colorforth div.CodeMirror-selected {
        background: #0004FF !important;
    }
    /* 3024-night theme */
    .cm-s-3024-night div.CodeMirror-selected {
        background: #0004FF !important;
    }

/** - - - - - **/
```

This solution applies to the AngularJS version of CodeMirror.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `mark-selection` add on and set the custom background-color.

1. import 'codemirror/addon/selection/mark-selection';
2. In case you need to reset the background color to default browser behavior then add this to your style `background-color: highlight;`

Answer (score 0):

In CodeMirror 6, use this to change the selection color:

```css
.cm-selectionBackground,
.cm-editor ::selection {
  background-color: #ccc !important;
}
```

The `.cm-selectionBackground` selector is used when you use the `drawSelection()` extension, which is part of the `basicSetup` set that the documentation recommends.

The `.cm-editor ::selection` selector is used to style the browser-native selection, in case you don't use `drawSelection()`.

To reset it to the browser's default, rather than `drawSelection`'s own choice of color, use this:

```css
.cm-selectionBackground {
  background-color: highlight !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is a CSS concern. Please refer to the following article:

[Overriding the Default Text Selection Color with CSS](http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/)

Comment: Codemirror uses it's own implementation of selection, hence this method doesn't work.